# Rails: How to redefine a Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-spring

I am trying to use Spring in my rails project but I have my own class called Spring that inherits from another class of mine called Feature.

In my code I call .superclass on a variable that is set to Spring sometimes. It fails because the variable is set to the other Spring class. How can I set it to class I defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would suggest use modules. 
create your class inside a module and call it `MyModule::Spring` to avoid conflicts